# Magento File Permissions + Strange errors

Tags: php, magento, permissions

I've just done a fresh install of Magento but I'm getting some bizarre errors:

For example within the admin area I go into System - Import / Export - Profiles ; then I just get

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 682005239838

I'm getting this pretty much everywhere... So I thought I'd upgrade Magento so went into Connect to do an upgrade: but when trying this I'm get also getting insufficient permission errors.

So I'm probably assuming that all of this is related.

Can anybody please advise, on what chmod permission I should set and on which folders? and Will this solve all my dramas?

Best Regards

Shane

Comment: You should check error log files to see what are the actual errors

Comment: I've managed to sort the general error messages out but still Connect is playing up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted!

php safe mode was switched on by accident! Doh!

Answer (score 0):

The file permissions should be:

MAGETO_ROOT/app/etc - writable

MAGETO_ROOT/media/  - writable

MAGETO_ROOT/var/ - writable

The rest folders and wiles should have regular permissions.

Now, about the error you have got. You should try open a file MAGETO_ROOT/var/reports/report/682005239838 and you will see more detailed where your problem is.

If you want to see your error reports without going to FTP -- just rename file MAGETO_ROOT/errors/local.xml.sample to MAGETO_ROOT/errors/local.xml